# Y a-t-il une nuance dans la signification des locutions « écorcher », « estropier » et « mal prononcer » en ce qu'il s'agit de prononciation ?

Tags: sens, nuance

Utilise-t-on uniquement l'une ou l'autre de ces locutions en fonction du fait que le mot ait été mal prononcé délibérément ou par méconnaissance ?

Sinon, le choix de locution dépendrait-elle du fait que le mot mal prononcé soit un nom propre ou pas ?

Answer (score 1):

Ces expressions sont effectivement utilisées pour les noms propres, mais c'est aussi avec les noms propres (et en particulier les noms d'origine étrangère) que l'on a le plus de chance de mal prononcer le mot.

'écorcher' va plutôt se réferer à une modification de l'ordre des lettres (comme dire 'aréoport' au lieu de 'aéroport'). 'estropier' signifie que l'on a 'manqué' quelque chose dans la prononciation (une syllabe, la prononciation d'un 's' à la fin). 'mal prononcé' pourra être utilisé lorsque la prononciation n'est pas correcte, lorsque l'on prononce le 'p' de 'compte' par exemple.